# How do I change the last textual node child in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### **My Solution (EDIT : 2015-12-08) :**

```js
// FIRST WE GET THE PARENT ELEMENT
var parentEstim = document.getElementById("onglet_estim");
// MAKE A TABLE OF HIS CHILD
var enfantsEstim = parentEstim.childNodes;
// KNOW HOW MANY CHILDREN THE PARENT ELEMENT HAVE WITH .length
var Nbenfants = enfantsEstim.length;
....
for (var i = 0; i <= Nbenfants; i++) {
      // IF THE CHILD ELEMENT [i] IS A HTML ELEMENT
      if (enfantsEstim[i].nodeType === 1) {
        enfantsEstim[i].lastChild.data = ''; // REMOVE LAST TEXT NODE
        enfantsEstim[i].classList.remove('isActive');
      }
      document.getElementById('onglet_estim').style.width = '220px';
      ClickedElement.className = 'isActive';
      // ADD NEW VALUE IN THE LAST TEXT NODE FOR THE CLICKED ELEMENT 
      ClickedElement.lastChild.data = ' Gares';
    }
```

DEMO : http://codepen.io/Zedash/details/pjMEMY

### **The Problem :**

I have a little *problem*, I want to change **the last textual node child** value of a link `<a>` element.

*For exemple*, for the first link, we see the word "**Saisie**" wrote in it and I want to remove the text in this element if the user click on an other link and add **a right text** for *the clicked element*.

```js
function changeInputAdresse(ClassName) {
  if (ClassName.className !== 'isActive') {
    ClassName.className = 'isActive';
    switch(ClassName.id) {
      case 'linkGares' :
        ClassName.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd',' Gares');
        ClassName.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('isActive');
        ClassName.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('isActive');
        ClassName.previousElementSibling.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd','');
        ClassName.nextElementSibling.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd','');
        break;
    }
  }
};
// THE CODE IS NOT FINISHED OF COURSE !
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a id="linkSaisie" class="isActive" href="#n" onclick="changeInputAdresse(this);"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Adresse</a>

<a id="linkGares" href="#n" onclick="changeInputAdresse(this);"><i class="fa fa-train"></i></a>

<a id="linkAeroports" href="#n" onclick="changeInputAdresse(this);"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i></a>

<a id="linkLoisirs" href="#n" onclick="changeInputAdresse(this);"><i class="fa fa-fort-awesome"></i></a>
<!--THE PART OF CODE WHERE I HAVE SOME PROBLEMS-->
```

Thanks for your ansewers ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get what you exactly would like, but to target and change the element after an italic I would use this jQuery and vanilla JS combination:

```
$("#myLink").find(">i").get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue = "Changed text";
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/u9jq2bvy/

IIRC there is no jQuery method to target a text node, so you need some native JS.
Please let me know if I misunderstood the question and I'm gonna delete my answer.

UPDATE

Based on the comment here is a possible solution.

```
$(document).on("click", ".myLink", function() {
  // clear all texts
  $(this).parent().find("a>span").text("");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(this).children("span").text("Active text");  
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/u9jq2bvy/1

And here is a modified version which simply shows/hides the spans.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/u9jq2bvy/3/

Comment: Thanks for your ansewer Zoltán Tamási !

I'm sorry for my bad explications I'll try to describe the problem,

I have **5 links**
one of them have a **text wote** in it
**When** someone **click** on a link and the link have **no text**
**So** the **function write** the proper text in the link clicked and **remove** all others text **from link element** (previous or next)

Comment: **Problem solved !**

Thank you for your help **Zoltán Tamási** I find how to do it with your exemple ;)

I'll post the solution for the others !

P.S : Sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
changeInputAdresse(element){
    element = $(element)
    if(!element.hasClass('isActive')){

        element.addClass('isActive');
        element.siblings().removeClass('isActive');

        element.text(element.attr('id').replace('link','')) //if that's the way you get value
        element.siblings().text('')
    }

}
```